My knowledge about this subject is not clear, so I want to _____ it. => strengthen?

My knowledge about this subject is not clear. I have been taught different pieces of knowledge related to it, but I can't remember them clearly. I'm often unsure about what I know, so I want to _____ my knowledge.

=> strengthen, consolidate, reinforce, solidify.
At first, I felt that all of these four words were correct for this context, but by what TimR said, the latter three are seemingly all bad, even though I've heard people in some videos using them to go with "knowledge". If none of them are correct, could you recommend an alternative?
Note that I feel words like "expand" or "broaden" deliver a different meaning from what I meant above.

This is a "Which is least bad?" sort of test question.  The question starts to go downhill  at "hazy".   Memory can be hazy.  Knowledge can't be hazy.

Now that you've edited, nor can knowledge be "not clear".

If you know what I mean, please help me. I honestly don't know what I should use to convey my idea here.

Instead of asking to choose between those three words, start over and come up with a question that offers an apt description of the knowledge. Then you'll know what needs to be done to improve that knowledge.

@TimR Oh I don't know: sometimes my knowledge feels rather hazy!

@AnIELTSLearner, if it helps, you might benefit from thinking what you mean by knowledge. For example, pieces of knowledge sounds like you are describing facts, while knowledge by itself could mean something at a deeper level: understanding or insight. The words you choose to describe this will vary accordingly.

I still haven't got what part in my description is hard to understand. I thought I described the context pretty clearly: You learn a subject with your friends and are taught the same knowledge. You friends remember and understand it thoroughly. You, on the other hand, don't understand some. You want to be like your friends, having a clear picture about this area of knowledge. When we say "expand", it has the nuance of learning more information. However in this case, you want to strengthen your knowledge, make it clear and understand it thoroughly. So you say: I want to ___ my knowledge.

@PeterKirkpatrick Oh, so you mean that knowledge doesn't work at all and my question should be about "my understanding" instead?

It's not "hard to understand".  The question had this form: Here's a crappy sentence where I don't much care about choosing words carefully. Which word of these three properly completes the next thought -- they all seem to be closely related -- is there a particular nuance that would make one of them the best choice?

It's not that I don't care about choosing words carefully. It's that I thought I knew how to use hazy correctly but it turned out that I didn't. I have formed this kind of question a lot in the past; some of them got many upvotes. It's just this time I made some mistakes as an English learner. I didn't find the original three words in any exam guide. I heard native speakers say it in Youtube videos and noted them down and felt they might deliver what I wanted to convey.

@AnIELTSLearner I'm not saying that knowledge is definitely the wrong word. I am saying that it may depend what you mean by it.

Some of the things that have struck others as problematic seem fine to me. I so no problem with referring to knowledge as something that can be broken into chunks and scattered; it certainly works that way sometimes. That being the case, some of your word choices address this metaphorical way of representing the knowledge. I think all the proposed words work, they just have different shades of meaning.
Really, all these words are representing the knowledge using some kind of metaphor.

"Strengthen": implies that the knowledge is weak.
"Consolidate": implies that the knowledge is scattered. This has been objected to, but I think it's fine especially since the previous sentences explained this concept: "I have been taught different pieces."
"Reinforce": also implies that the knowledge is weak. There is little difference here from "strengthen" for this context; the difference between the words is that to "strengthen" something can be to help it develop its own internal strength (like a muscle), while to "reinforce" it is to add external strength (like an ankle brace).
"Solidify": implies that the knowledge is... well, un-solid. Maybe "diffuse" or "soft." We do use this metaphor for thoughts often: "I don't have a solid understanding of this idea."
"Broaden" and "deepen" imply that the knowledge is too narrow or too shallow (respectively). You're right, this is a bit specialized. Maybe I know a lot about dolphins. I might "broaden" my knowledge by learning about other marine life, or "deepen" it by learning even more about dolphins.

But if you want something very safe and applicable in the most circumstances, you can just say "I want to INCREASE my knowledge." The only implication here is that the knowledge is "not enough."

According to Merriam-Webster consolidate can mean "to make firm or secure" or "to join together into one whole" (your joining scattered knowledge), either of which could apply here.

Using a dictionary definition to decide whether a word should be used in a given context often results in poor word choices.  I don't think someone can consolidate their own knowledge.  An article that synthesizes the extant research on a topic might be said to consolidate the scattered knowledge.

@TimR Welp, agree to disagree; I think one can! We use the metaphor "scatterbrained" (though that's a red herring because it's more about attention than knowledge). But I could totally imagine saying "My learning in this area has been piecemeal and my knowledge is scattered; I need to consolidate it." Though now that we're challenging it, it would probably be better to say "I need to fill in the gaps."

@AndyBonner  It's not that I cannot imagine someone saying it, but that the resulting phrase wouldn't make much sense.  What would it mean, to "consolidate piecemeal knowledge"?  It doesn't  mean "to fill in the gaps" (yes, much better indeed) but "to bring together".

The first part of the description needs some tidying up.  I leave that aside and address this on word choice:

I'm often unsure about what I know, so I want to _____ my knowledge.

We could consider improve my knowledge.  These work too: increase, extend, and enhance.

Thank you. Don't "increase" and "extend" mean the same as "broaden" or "expand" in this case?

Yes, they are similar.  You can try them out in the ludwig link.    Usually I check several sources to see whether the proposed words are frequently used.  In our case here, those I have suggested are.

Knowledge in a particular subject area is often said to require a firm foundation; it's a cliche.  It wouldn't surprise me in the least to find  the question asked here in an exam prep guide or on an exam, using that cliche. The triad of possibilities originally provided before the edits, consolidate, reinforce, and solidify, seem to be extensions of that figure of speech. I would put my money on solidify or reinforce since the foundation needs to be firm.
P.S. That's why I questioned OP's original  phrase that the knowledge was "hazy", which adjective was intended to establish the context for choosing between the three alternatives. But  that adjective didn't comport with any of those possibilities. Nor did the edit, that the knowledge was "not clear".
